# How to Get Response From rest URL using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a URL https://aua.maharashtra.gov.in/aua/rest/checkauastatus

When I visit the URL in a browser, I get an XML response.  I want to collect that response in a String using Javascript or jQuery.  I tried many things but nothing worked.

Please help me to get that response in a String.

Comment: have you REALLY tried anything? A simple `$.ajax` would solve that

Comment: Please post what you have tried so we can go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url:'https://aua.maharashtra.gov.in/aua/rest/checkauastatus',
   success: function(response)
   {
      alert(response);
   }
```

Just see if your expected reponse is coming or not.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling ajax with ***`different domain`*** , then ajax will not work, You have to call your server and collect data. For e.g using ***`curl, then return as response`***. You can also use `jsonp` if it supports.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make a request to other domains, use the below code for reference.

```
    $.ajax({
            url: 'https://aua.maharashtra.gov.in/aua/rest/checkauastatus',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'dataResult',
            jsonp: 'callback',
        });
   function dataResult(data) {
       //Access your data here.
   };
```